# Power supply question - ramp up

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, current, switch-mode-power-supply

I'd like to understand what is the meaning of monotonic ramp up of a power supply.

What does it mean?

Any there any other types of power supply ramp ups, as well?

Comment: Just to be sure, have you looked up the word from your native language dictionary for English words?

Comment: @Justme , yes I did check. But unsure how power supply is related to this word.

Comment: "Monotonic" means either "always increasing" or "always decreasing." So a monotonic ramp up just means that something increases from zero to its final value without ever dipping.

Comment: This is really just a question about the meaning of words. Maybe you should expand the question to include more context from where you read this. If the author used the word "monotonic" this means they wanted to exclude the condition where something (a voltage or current) has a dip in it. I am not sure why that would be a key point. But maybe if you add more context to the question someone will be able to explain it.

Comment: I think what you are trying to understand is a soft shutdown or a soft start up of a power converter. The essence of this is whenever you have a DC bus to regulate upto for example of 600V. Instead directly ramping up to 600V, we slowly increase the Vdc to 600V to limit high surge currents into the Electrolytic capacitors. Same goes while shuting off the converter too!

Comment: Please add the context you relate to, a snippet from the datasheet etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does it mean?

As others have stated in the comments, monotonic ramp up or monotonic rise is basically an output voltage start-up behaviour **without any ramp down or fall**. Monotonic rise is generally defined/required for a range *(e.g. monotonic rise between 10% and 90%)*. The table below is taken from the [datasheet](https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/power/switching-power/ac-dc-converter/catalog/mu_e.pdf) of a TDK-Lambda power supply:

[image]

Depending on the specs/requirements, instant or temporary flats in the range may or may not be acceptable, but generally acceptable.

Here are some different start-up behaviours:

[image]

<sup>Grey lines indicate nominal/target values.</sup>

- A shows a "perfect" monotonic rise.
- B shows a monotonic rise with turn-on overshoot. This may or may not be acceptable depending on the design and its specs. Some designs may allow some overshoot e.g. 10% turn-on overshoot.
- C shows a non-monotonic rise as it shows a temporary fall. However, if the spec requires monotonic rise for a range (e.g. 10% to 90% of nominal voltage) and if the non-monotonic behaviour happens outside this range then it still might be acceptable. *This behaviour can be seen on frequency-controlled converters when testing them with an electronic load which generally don't show any behaviour (constant resistance or constant current) below some voltage level (e.g. 1.5V). So, the power supply starts without any load because the electronic load is basically inactive, so the output voltage may rise quicker than it does when loaded. Then, once the output hits the electronic load's threshold the load kicks in and loads the power supply. This causes a temporary drop in the output voltage but the power supply recovers and shows a proper ramp-up behaviour. Output capacitance generally has a positive effect on this i.e. the higher it is the better ramp up.*

Comment: This is a good answer Rohat and if I may, curve C could potentially be rejected because of the temporary neg. slope. I remember customers rejecting this signature, arguing that the microcontroller would hang in this portion: a flat pause was acceptable, but not a neg. slope. If this is sometimes a challenge for a single-output converter, these monotonic specs can quickly become a headache in multi-output converters such as ATX PSUs for instance. I looked at these details in may [APEC 2015](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202015.pdf) seminar.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer!